# How do I validate nested properties using anyOf

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm struggling to write a validation rule using json-schema. Here is my data in json format:

```
{
    "headers" : {
        "api_key" : "aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee"
    },
    "query_string" : {
        "apikey" : "aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee"
    }
}
```

I need a rule that says:

> At least "headers->api_key" or "query_string->apikey" needs to be present in the json, but not both.

Here is my schema validation so far:

```
{
  "title": "Application Get Single",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "headers": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "api_key": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "query_string": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "apikey": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {"required": ["headers"["api_key"]]}, // what should this be??
    {"required": ["query_string"["apikey"]]} // what should this be??
  ]
}
```

I think it's `anyOf` I'm looking for but I don't know how to refer to a nested json items above.

At the moment I get an error:

> JSON syntax is malformed

I'm using [Justin Rainbow](https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema) as I'm working with PHP for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways.  The most straightforward is:

```
{
  "title": "Application Get Single",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "headers": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "api_key": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "query_string": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "apikey": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "headers": {
            "type": "object",
            "required":["api_key"]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "query_string": {
            "type": "object",
            "required":["apikey"]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You would probably also want `"minProperties": 1` on the root object in order to ensure that either headers or query_string exist.

**EDIT**: Just re-read the question and if headers.api_key and query_string.apikey are mutually exclusive change `anyOf` to `oneOf`

Answer (score 1):

The trick is the "and not the other" part.  Here's what I'd recommend (assuming draft-06 or later, see below for draft-04):

```
{
  "title": "Application Get Single",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "headers": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "api_key": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "query_string": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "apikey": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "required": ["headers"],
      "query_string": false
    },
    {
      "required": ["query_string"],
      "headers": false
    }
  ]
}
```

For draft-04, replace `false` with `{"not": {}}` which means the same thing but is annoying to read.  But you can't use boolean schemas in most places in draft-04 so you need the verbose way of saying "this property must not be present".